# Can I use android app bundle to generate required APK on my server?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have a self build APK distribution infrastructure where I place my multiple APK's based on OEM's and then specifc APK is downloaded to specific OEM device. Now since the introduction of app bundles in android, I wonder if I can provide a specific apk to specifc devices by generating them from my app bundle on the fly? I have the bundle but I do not know how can I generate APK from it on my server. I also cant see any service provided by Google for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bundletool via command line to generate the apk from your server, and then serve the output files to the OEMs, as almost every backend techonologies offers command line interfaces.

https://github.com/google/bundletool

Note that they provide a .jar file, so you may have to have java installed in your server's machine.

You may call the bundletool .jar like bellow

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/bundletool-all-0.3.3.jar build-apks 
--bundle=your_bundle_path 
--output=out_bundle_archive_set.apks
```

source: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-part-2-bundletool-6705b50bea4c

Official documentation link (As Pierre suggested): https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: Consider adding a link to the full public documentation as well: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool 
It contains the description of all the flags for all the commands.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just one more thing , I have OEM specific signing, can app-bundle have OEM specific signing ? And if yes then will the APK generated from OEM signed bundle have the same signing as well?